# How do I attach an access key to a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to use `accesskey` attribute but it requires user to use combinations of keys but I want to use a single key to access the element. I tried to search it on web I couldn't find any thing.

Comment: Only possible using Javascript.

Comment: can you tell me how

Comment: What do you mean by access? Like focus the element? Have you tried the onkeypress JavaScript event?

Comment: by access I mean to activate and onKeypress doesn't work sins I have to assign the specific keys to the specific elements

Comment: The way to activate the accesskey depends on the browser and its platform mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey), you can't activate access key with single key press as mentioned there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the help of Javascript **but you really shouldn't** as the accesskeys natively available require a modifier for very good reasons.

Please note that this effectively disallows to use the keys assigned to accesskeys to be used for anything other than accessing those elements (e.g. you can no longer type those letters in an input), **which is why this is not an acceptable solution**.

I'm just showing it to demonstrate the general technical approach.

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  const target = document.querySelector(`[data-accesskey=${event.key.toLowerCase()}]`);
  if (target) {
    target.focus();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" data-accesskey="n" placeholder="Press n to focus this field" />
<button type="button" data-accesskey="p">Press p to focus this button</button>
```